# PHP: Inserting Array of Integers into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, integer

I have a MySQL table in which I have a column where I want to insert multiple integers, comma seperated. (like 1,2,3,4).
I am passing these integer values from a form and I receive them correctly on my php file as an array:

> Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 4 )

But now I want to insert this into my database, but I keep getting:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in

This is how I am receiving my post values and putting them into an array:

```
$project_type = substr($_POST['project_type'], 0, -1); //the substring to remove the last comma
$project_type_array = explode(',', $project_type);
```

And this is how I am inserting it:

```
$SQL_project_has_type = "INSERT INTO project_has_project_type(project_ID_project, project_type_ID_project_type)
VALUES('{$row['ID_project']}', {$project_type_array})";

mysql_query($SQL_project_has_type);
```

Any help is welcome, thanks!

Comment: why you want to make it integer instead of varchar? Its not possible to have comma in number.

Answer (score 0):

encode the array to json before you store in the database and decode the object to array when you are reading the value.
In php you can encode by calling json_encode() and get back original array by using json_decode().

Answer (score 0):

To insert array into database you can serialize the array like

```
 $project_type_array = serialize( $project_type_array );
```

And unserialize to use from database.

If you want to insert data as ( 1,2,3 ) only, then apply a foreach on array and make a string
of the values like

```
$value = '';
foreach( $project_type_array as $val ){

    $value = $val.',';

}

$value = rtrim( $value, ',' ); // to remove last comma from the string
```

Comment: That might work, but I need to store the data as an integer in the database (because of a foreign key to another table). So is it possible to store data like: 3,4,5,6 (with the comma) as an integer in the table?

Comment: no, you can use that as text only, for integer there should only be one integer value.
If you want to search a key from this string ( 1,2,3 ), then you can use find_in_set() funtion of mysql.

find_in_set( search string, column );

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php

$array = Array ( 0 => 3 ,1 => 4 );
$project_type_array = implode(',',$array);

print_r($project_type_array);

$SQL_project_has_type = "INSERT INTO project_has_project_type(project_ID_project, project_type_ID_project_type)
VALUES('".$row['ID_project']."','".$project_type_array."')";

mysql_query($SQL_project_has_type); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix it, I think I didn't explain my problem well. Basically I was trying to insert multiple foreign keys into one row, so what I now did is to insert multiple rows with the same ID, but different foreign keys, with a for loop:

```
$project_type = substr($_POST['project_type'], 0, -1);
$project_type_array = explode(',', $project_type);

for($i = 0; $i < count($project_type_array); ++$i){
    $SQL_project_has_type = "INSERT INTO project_has_project_type(project_ID_project,project_type_ID_project_type)
    VALUES('{$row['ID_project']}', {$project_type_array[$i]})";
    mysql_query($SQL_project_has_type);
    }
```

That did the job. Thanks for the help anyways.